# How to get model equation/coefficients for SVM in Orange

Tags: svm, orange

I have dataset and want to train an SVM model, I have done so in Orange, and the model behaves good, I used the File -> SVM -> 'test and score' widgets, now I want to take that linear model and implement it in C code,

from literature, I know the hyperplane can be represented mathematically and then you can use the equation to classify depending on the result sign, where can I find that equation/coefficients in Orange?

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, you can always use [Python Script widget](https://orangedatamining.com/widget-catalog/transform/pythonscript/) and extract the coefficients from the classifier yourself.